# Help me with this Java code

Tags: java, copy-constructor

**Question**:

```
matrix m1 = new matrix(); // should produce a matrix of 3*3

matrix m2 = new matrix(5,4); //5*4

matrix m3 = new matrix(m2); //5*4
```

What should be there in the copy constructor to make a new matrix m3 of the same order as of m2?

```
 public class matrix {

    int a[ ][ ];

       matrix(){
        a = new int[3][3];  
      }

     matrix(int x, int y){
        a= new int [x][y];      
      }

     matrix (matrix b1){        
      //how to use value of x and y here....
      }

void show(){

        System.out.println(a.length);
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
            System.out.print(a[i].length);      
            }
        } 
     }




public class matrixtest { 

public static void main(String [ ] args){   

       matrix a = new matrix();     
       matrix b = new matrix(5,4);  
       matrix c  = new matrix (b);  
       a.show(); 

       b.show(); 

       c.show(); 
   } 

}
```

NOTE: You can not use any extra instance variable except the array a.

**Accepted answer**: @Chankey: this(b1.a.length,b1.a[0].length); – [John](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571189/john)

Comment: use   a =new int[b1.a.length][b1.a[0].length];

Comment: `this(b1.a.length,b1.a[0].length);`

Comment: Just to add, it's**preferred** that your class names starts with a Capital Letter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Store the number of rows, and the number of columns in the matrix class, and create getters for them.

```
public class Matrix {
    int[][] a;
    int rowNum;
    int colNum;

    //...
    public Matrix(Matrix b) {
       a=new int[b.getRowNum()][b.getColNum()];
       this.rowNum = b.getRowNum();
       this.colNum = b.getColNum();
    }

    public int getRowNum() {
       return this.rowNum;
    }


}
```

Comment: +1 for object oriented and encapsulated answer (not accessing `b.a` directly)!

Comment: Thanks but I know this method. I was asked to solve the problem without using any instance variables. John has already given the solution in the comment but I think I should accept your answer too. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the size of the passed `b1` matrix

```
int x = b1.length;
int y = b1[0].lenght;
```

and can then use it to construct the final array.

```
a= new int [x][y];
```

Comment: b1 doesn't have length attributes, it's not an array.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
  a =new int[b1.a.length][b1.a[0].length];
```

But it is not recommended . 
you should have some get method , which return 
matrix dimension.

Answer (score 1):

This is homework, so I'll give you a hint:

How would you get the lengths of the 2 dimensional matrix (`a[][]`) of b1? proper methods in the matrix class will help - how would you implement those (getX, getY)?

Also, it is better to redirect the constructors to the most detailed one, for example:

```
matrix(){
    this(3,3);  // call the constructor below with parameters 3,3
  }

 matrix(int x, int y){
  a= new int [x][y];      
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be the most probable answer without using any other instance variable other then the array itself:

```
import java.io.*;
class matrix
{
private int arr[][];
public matrix() //Default Constructor
{
    this(3,3);
}

public matrix(int r,int c) //Parameterized Constructor
{
    arr=new int[r][c];
    read();
}

public matrix(matrix m)  //Copy Constructor
{
    System.out.println("Fetching array...");
    int r,c;
    r=m.arr.length;
    c=m.arr[0].length;
    arr=new int [r][c];
    for(int i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<c;j++)
        {
            arr[i][j]=m.arr[i][j];
        }
    }
}

public void read()
{
    int i,j,r,c;
    r=arr.length;
    c=arr[0].length;
    Console con=System.console();
    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
        {
            arr[i][j]=Integer.parseInt(con.readLine());
        }
    }
}
public void show()
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<arr[0].length;j++)
        {
            System.out.print(" "+arr[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

}